# Focus on another widget when the keyboard is opened in Flutter

Tags: flutter

There is a TextField on my screen to write a comment. Everything is working correctly now, but when the TextField is clicked, I want to focus on the Column where the comments are located.

My purpose in doing this is to show the first comment on the screen when the keyboard is opened.

I have tried FocusNode and Focus widget on my code.

I initialize it and used. When I add onTap in TextField and use myFocusNode.nextFocus(), the keyboard does not open. How can we fix it?

```dart
final myFocusNode = FocusNode();
...
...
TextField(
              controller: happeningsRead.happeningCommentTextController,
              onTap: () {
                myFocusNode.nextFocus();
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                hintText: 'addYourComment'.tr(),
),
...
...
Focus(
                focusNode: myFocusNode,
                child: Column(...),
)
```

Comment: Define "focus on the Column" please.

Comment: Naturally you cannot have a focus on two elements at the same time.

Comment: @offworldwelcome When the TextField is clicked, the keyboard opens, but the first comment remains under the keyboard, the user can see the comment by scrolling down. I am trying to show the first comment.

Comment: @user18309290 I've recorded example video https://youtube.com/shorts/SQLjQ98nTaY I try to make it so that the first comment is shown as in the last seconds of the video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a bit curious about this issue, and took a bit to try to understand what was actually your issue, and I am happy I took the time because I just learned a new trick. :D

So basically what you want is **not** to use **Focus** but to use a property of the textField called **scrollPadding**

If you figure out how to get the exact distance to the bottom of the comment, you can use it on this property to set the keyboard just under it. Or in the alternative just set a default height like in this example:

```
Textfield( 
scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:50),
// ... your code
```

Comment: Awesome I just found this at the same time you :D I also found the Scrollable.ensureVisible() method that might work. Thanks.